# Numpy QR factorization wrong dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

When using numpys QR factorization one gets a $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{mxn}$ and $R\in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ while in Matlab one gets $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{mxm}$ and $R\in \mathbb{R}^{mxn}$, my question is wheter there is a easy way to get a similar factorization as matlab using numpy?

I have tried to look for a alternative QR decomposition in numpy to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your matrix is `M`...

```
q,r = np.linalg.qr(M, mode='complete')
```